# Como criar uma classe abstrata no C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, classes-abstratas

Em C++ usa virtual

arquivo .cpp

```
#ifndef TETES_H
#define TETES_H


    class Tetes
    {
        public:
            Tetes();
            virtual ~Tetes();
          virtual void exibeDados();
        protected:
        private:
    };

    #endif // TETES_H
```

arquivo .h

```
#include "Tetes.h"

Tetes::Tetes()
{
    //ctor
}

Tetes::~Tetes()
{
    //dtor
}
```

arquivo .cpp

```
#ifndef TETES1_H
#define TETES1_H


    class Tetes1 : public Testes
    {
        public:
            Tetes1();
            virtual ~Tetes1();
           void exibeDados()
         {
           cout << "Exibe na Tela" << endl; 
          }
        protected:
        private:
    };

    #endif // TETES1_H
```

arquivo .h

```
#include "Tetes1.h"

Tetes1::Tetes1()
{
    //ctor
}

Tetes1::~Tetes1()
{
    //dtor
}
```

... mais classe `teste2`, `test3` com mesma função porém diferente seu conteúdo.

Mas dá um erro

```
undefined reference to Testes::exibeDados()
```

Onde tenho que referenciar e como? É assim que se define uma classe abstrata em C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é o único problema, mas além dos nomes dos arquivos estarem invertidos na pergunta, a classe abstrata chama-se `Tetes` e depois `Tetes1` é herdada de `Teste`. Já tem um problema aí. Possivelmente causando outros.

Fora isso, pode ser que não esteja sendo compilado tudo na mesma unidade de compilação, ou *linkado* junto, mas só vendo o código não dá para saber.

E também é necessário declarar explicitamente o método virtual na classe abstrata como sem implementação. Isso é feito com `= 0`:

```
virtual void exibeDados() = 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/AbstractMethod.cpp).

Comment: Foi erro meu na digitação não é Teste é Testes

Comment: Erros de digitação causam problemas e seu código parece ter vários.

Comment: quando tiro o  função virtual exibeDados () do Teste funciona

Comment: Tinha esquecido de um detalhe.

Comment: agora deu certo